# Ввод дат в asp.net core с корректной проверкой в хроме

Tags: c#, html, google-chrome, asp.net-core, дата

У меня есть совершенно тривиальный код по вводу даты в формах asp.net core, всё в полном согласии с официальными рекомендациями:

```
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Created" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Created" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Created" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

И я пользовался им всегда и не знал горя, пока случайно не пришлось открыть этот код в браузере хром с мобильного.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оказалось - в этом браузере был (есть?) баг при попытке ввода даты (просто переставляя день на завтра-послезавтра) - почему-то дата считается неверной

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, вот тут на [en so есть вопрос и ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19284193/5752652), датированные древним 2013 и 2016 годом. По проявлениям - баг один-в-один, однако у меня asp.net уже генерирует именно type="datetime-local"

Также я нашёл [рекомендацию](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19504018/5752652) проставить step="1", однако хотя и проблема кажется смежной - это всё-таки не она.

Насколько я понял - проблема в том, что при первоначальном заполнении из БД указываются не только секунды, но и тики - а при попытке смены из браузера тики очищаются.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобными проблемами? Есть идеи, как вводить дату на современных chrome-браузерах в asp.net core?

Генерируемая разметка (с добавленным step):

```
<input class="form-control"
       step="1"
       type="datetime-local"
       data-val="true"
       data-val-required="The Created field is required."
       id="Created"
       name="Created"
       value="2019-08-08T06:52:14.893">
```

Comment: Версия браузера?

Comment: Что с атрибутами min или max - они генерируются?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Не генерируются, по крайней мере в обычной версии, а не в мобильной версии. Уточню, когда поставлю [инспектор](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14734124/5752652), пока добавил в вопрос разметку из десктопного хрома (я пока исхожу из предположения, что они одинаковые  -- т.е. что сгенерировала серверная сторона - то хром и отобразит без каких-либо модификаций)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выглядит так, как будто step откладывается от даты по умолчанию (видимо, в этом и заключалось исправление найденного вами бага), а стандартный редактор даты-времени сбрасывает миллисекунды в 0 - а потому не способен дать валидного значения.

Попробуйте очистить младшие разряды времени (миллисекунды и опционально секунды) перед формированием инпута:

```
Created = Created.AddMilliseconds(-Created.Millisecond)
```